# Reading Data from SQL via MSSQL Node.js

Tags: node.js, sql-server

Can you please assist me with as I new for Node.js and JavaScript?

I have below code where I am pushing SQL Query to the DB in order to get values from column called "ID"

```
var Number = 123456789;
var request = new sql.Request();
request.query("SELECT ID FROM Servers", function (err, recordset) 
{
  if (err) console.log(err)
});
```

So what I want is to check, if value which is in Number variable is existing or not in the recordset which I received from SQL Query.

Comment: request query is wrong, concatenate the variable `ID` to the query first. Then use an aggregate function `count` to check whether such ID is present or not. If the result is 0 then it`s not, else it is.

Comment: query is correct just maybe I couldn't understand it correctly, I want to get all the ID which is in the "Server" DB table under column called "ID" to some array field and after that check that array with the ID variable (var ID = 123456789;) ıf there are some values matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do that with a single query like this :

```
var ID = 123456789;
var request = new sql.Request();
request.query("SELECT ID FROM Servers WHERE ID = " + ID, function (err, recordset)
{
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(recordset);
});
```

You also can make your query with templating :

```
request.query(`SELECT ID FROM Servers WHERE ID = ${ID}`, function ...
```

**EDIT**

If you really want to get all IDs and compare after in you code, you can do something like this :

```
var ID = 123456789;
var request = new sql.Request();
request.query('SELECT ID FROM Servers', function (err, recordset)
{
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < recordset.length; i++) {
            if (recordset[i].ID == ID) {
                console.log('Match here !');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for response, my point is actually get all values from DB table in ID column to Node.js Array and after that compare them with the ID variable.

Comment: "recordset.length" is failling because it is returning "undefined" when I am checking it with console.log(recordset.length); any advise here ?

Comment: Humm.. What looks like console.log(recordset) ?

Comment: output of console.log(recordset) was "undefined", I just fixed it with doing "results.recordset.length;"